# I need to erase a marked object from one image in my mac application. Is there anyway to do like that?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to eraze a marked object from one image in my mac application. We can mark the objects in an image with a brush. So that after applying the erase effect the selected object should be removed and that space should be filled with a matching background. Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Core Image filters. Here is [CIFilter reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).

To erase You need to use CISourceOutCompositing.

**Example:**

```
CIImage *yourBgImage = ... //from what image You want to cut
CIImage *markedObject = ... //Your painted image

CIFilter *sourceOut = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CISourceOutCompositing"];
[sourceOut setValue: markedObject forKey: @"inputImage"];
[sourceOut setValue: yourBgImage forKey: @"inputBackgroundImage"];

CIImage *result = [sourceOut valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
```

*result* is Your output image, erased image.

Comment: @JobinJose I added example. Hope it helps. Good luck!